# ELEMENT <i> into IF condition

Tags: html, tags, blazor

Why can't I use the   tag in a quick condition?

The code is as follows:
@ (company.Fax! = null? "< i class =" fas fa-fax " > :" + company.Fax: null)

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

You can't use HTML like `<i ...> </i>` in the render section. It will be escaped and show as `<i >` on the screen.

The easiest solution is an `@if` :

```
@if(company.Fax != null)
{
   <i class = "fas fa-fax"> </i>: company.Fax
}
```

if you do want to use the `?:` operator it has to look something like

```
@((MarkupString) (company.Fax != null? "<i class=\"fas fa-fax\" > </i>:" + company.Fax : null))
```